# Bootstrap modal is showing on top only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hi I am using a table on clicking of plus icon a bootstrap modal appears but if I go down of table and click on plus icon the modal appears at top. Can anyone please help me how to show modal at center of the screen even if I scroll to down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the bootstrap modal is opened a

> modal-open

class is set to the `<body>` tag. This class will set the `overflow: hidden;` to the body. Adding this rule to your stylesheet/css will override the bootstrap.css style:

`body.modal-open {
    overflow: visible;
}`